# How to count number of <br> tags inside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have:

```
<div class="words-container">
  <div class="words">
    here are words<br>
    here are words<br>
    here are words<br>
    here are words<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using Javascript or jQuery, how would I count the exact amount of `<br>` tags that are populated in the "words" div? I need a way to know how many lines there are.

Not sure what I'm doing here:

```
$countWords = $('.words-container')
if ($countWords.length) {
  var hahaha = $('.words').find('<br>').length
  console.log(hahaha.length)
}
```

Comment: `$('.words').find('br').`

Comment: You've called `length` twice. Remove it from `console.log(hahaha.length)`. Voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 1):

You could count the number of newlines in the text representation of your node (found via `innerText` property), or count the number of `<br>` tags with jQuery:

```js
$('.words').each(function() {
  // count newlines
  const lines = (this.innerText.match(/\n/g) || '').length
  console.log(lines);
  // or, count tags
  console.log($('br', this).length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="words-container">
  <div class="words">
    here are words<br>
    here are words<br>
    here are words<br>
    here are words<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I'm doing a `.each()` here, because `$('.words')` doesn't strictly resolve to just one element, it's a group of elements.

In order the find the number of tags, I use the [initialiser variant with context](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) to select the `<br>` tags inside of `this` (which is each element with `words` class.

If you just want to count direct descendent `<br>` elements inside all parents with `word` class, you'd do

```js
$('.words > br').length
```

Comment: I know you've followed the title, but the question does just state: `how would I count the exact amount of <br> tags that are populated in the "words" div?`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Updated with a way to count tags as well.

Comment: That's true, but I'd still recommend counting the value from the source, instead of the browsers interpretation of the text created from the source

Answer (score 1):

Native approach

`document.getElementsByClassName('words')[0].getElementsByTagName('br').length`

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this.

```
<div class="words-container">
  <div class="words">
    here are words<br>
    here are words<br>
    here are words<br>
    here are words<br>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    $countWords = $('.words-container')
    if ($countWords.length) {
        var hahaha = $('.words').find('br').length
        alert(hahaha)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```js
console.log($('.words-container .words br').length) // 4
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="words-container">
  <div class="words">
    here are words<br>
    here are words<br>
    here are words<br>
    here are words<br>
  </div>
</div>
```